# Hacker News algorithm in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, algorithm, ruby-on-rails-4

The HN algorithm:

```
(p - 1) / (t + 2)^1.5
```

Where:

```
p = votes of question and first answer
t = age in hours
```

Considering a links model with the following fields:

```
up_votes
down_votes
created_at
```

Is this implementation correct in Ruby on Rails? I'm not sure if it is:

```
def rank(link)
  p = link.up_votes - link.down_votes
  t = (Time.now - link.created_at).to_i / 60 / 60
  return (p - 1) / (t + 2)**1.5
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All looks fine from what you described. The only thing which might be a problem is using `/` operator. This operator returns integer if both operands are integers (i.e. `5/2 = 2`), however using `**` with float value always returns float (even when value is integer, e.g. `9**1.5 = 27.0`) so you are safe here.

Also it would be nice to use `/ 60**2` instead of `/ 60 / 60`. I would probably use:

```
t = ((Time.now - link.created_at) / 1.hour).round
```

I think it wouldn't hurt to remove round bit.